# swagger codegen --> angular6: rxjs observable compile error

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, codegen, rxjs6

When using to angular 6 and swagger codegen, i'm getting typescript compiler errors related to `rxjs`:

`Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'`

I found the following
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#rxjs-v5x-to-v6-update-guide

I'm using `swagger-codegen: stable 2.3.1` on a mac (installed with brew).

I appreciate any guidance.

Update -----------------------

I added `rxjs-compat` to my angular6 project using

`npm install --save-dev rxjs-compat`

I now get compiler warnings, but the compiler errors are gone and the project seems to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are migrating from a previous angular version, follow the following guide:

https://update.angular.io/

The `rxjs-compat` package is to have compatibility with previous `rxjs` implementations. For example:

`import { concat } from 'rxjs/observable/concat'`

However, that should be updated to the new implementation that comes along version 6. For example:

`import { catchError, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`

That said. You also have to change the implementation of your observable operators using `pipe`. For example:

```
this.sampleService
      .search(
        payload.firstName,
        payload.lastName,
        payload.dateOfBirth
      )
      .pipe(
        map(response => new sampleActions.SearchSuccess(response.json())),
        catchError(error => of(new sampleActions.SearchFail(error)))
      )
```

As you can see, the operators `map` and `catchError` have a different implementation, using the `pipe` operator.

Maybe you can share a copy of the logs, so it will be easier to understand what is causing errors/warns.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.

Even by replacing swagger generator with 2.4 didn't fix the issue, the workaround I found was to add rxjscompat to the project: `npm install rxjs-compat@6`

See more details on the discussion: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/8179#issuecomment-402575414

Answer (score 1):

For me, I used the "swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.0.jar" to generate, and to solve the "rxjs" issues, I added this at the end of the command:

```
--additional-properties ngVersion=6
```